# How to convert this particular varchar to human readable date format?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I want to convert `actual_arrival` and `actual_departure` to human readable date and then see everything as a simple table. For now I'm getting an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

How to do that?

```
Declare @json varchar(MAX) = '
{"stops": 
            {
                "type": "stop",
                "name": "stops",
                "company_id": "xxx",
                "actual_arrival": "20210910130000-0500",
                "actual_departure": "20210910140000-0500"}
}';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON ( @json, '$.stops' )             
WITH (          
            Type Varchar(50) '$.type',
            Name Varchar(50) '$.name',
            CompID Varchar(100) '$.company_id' ,
            AcArrvl DATETIME '$.actual_arrival' ,
            AcDprtr DATETIME '$.actual_departure') as j1
```

Comment: What output do you expect from the sample data?

Comment: Table with all columns from "type" to "AcDprtr" (as you see there are 5 of them )

Comment: That doesn't explain "human readable date". Does the count of base cycle croutons since the wheel was invented (`"20210910130000-0500"`) become "Half past the freckle on Blursday in the Orbital Reckoning of The Great Nonce"? Clearly not, because you only want the _date_, so freckles don't count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the formatting of the datetimeoffset. Also you are probably looking to convert into `datetimeoffset` to preserv time offset? This works for me (not that pretty but you have to reformat the string to `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss-hh:mm`):

```
Declare @json varchar(MAX) = '
{"stops": 
            {
                "type": "stop",
                "name": "stops",
                "company_id": "xxx",
                "actual_arrival": "20210910130000-0500",
                "actual_departure": "20210910140000-0500"}
}';

SELECT 
Type,
Name,
CompID,
CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,
    STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(AcArrvl,
    18,0,':'),
    13,0,':'),
    11,0,':'),
    9,0,' '),
    7,0,'-'),
    5,0,'-')
) AcArrvl,
CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET,
    STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(AcDprtr,
    18,0,':'),
    13,0,':'),
    11,0,':'),
    9,0,' '),
    7,0,'-'),
    5,0,'-')
) AcDprtr

FROM OPENJSON ( @json, '$.stops' )             
WITH (          
            Type Varchar(50) '$.type',
            Name Varchar(50) '$.name',
            CompID Varchar(100) '$.company_id' ,
            AcArrvl VARCHAR(100) '$.actual_arrival' ,
            AcDprtr VARCHAR(100) '$.actual_departure') as j1
```